# Java 2D Game Development - Best Performance With Rendering

Tags: java, performance, graphics, 2d, render

I have seen two different rendering methods. One of them is rendering multiple bufferedImages like g.drawImage(imag1 to imagexxx, x ,y). Like my game i have to render each tick 880 buffered images. And it is very bad. I have good computer but my max fps is 140. There should be another way to get better performance.

Second is drawing one single bufferedImage and setting its pixels to RGB from our other bufferedImages.

What is the best way ? Is there another way to get better performance ?

Comment: Why don't you try with both? In a real-life situation if you can, that's always better than as a micro-benchmark. Use `System.nanoSeconds` for time measurement and do some research about performance tuning.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I have already done. But i really cant figure it out what is going on. I downloaded another project(2D Game). He used same method as i use. He has 500 600 fps but i have 140. I really cant understand. And i have methods for rendering efficency. Like dont draw outside the screen bla bla. But my fps is to low.

Comment: If the frame rate is not restricted, and he has a better computer, then his frame rate will be higher. My computer gets around 300 to 400 (unrestricted), while others can reach up to 2k+. But in reality, you only need about 24 fps to simulate real-time animations. It's the standard for TVs. Games usually run at 30-60 fps, so what's the big deal?

Comment: Consider using a BufferStrategy, which allows you to control the number of backing buffers, but allow it to manage which buffer is available to be rendered to. This is commonly known as page flipping. Focus on time based animation, so if the frame rate does drop, the animation can adjust automatically. I also agree with Vince, realistically 25-60fps is more then enough and can give the cpu time to process other things

Comment: Generally, the less you have to do on each pass, the better, so try and generate any static (or slow changing) content onto a single buffer and reuse this